# Tap Draw On a Section of the Screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, canvas, draw

I'm trying to make my app be able to draw with your finger like Snapchat on part of the screen but not the whole thing? Every example I have seen of drawing is just an app that turns your whole screen into the canvas and does nothing else but I'm having a hard time implementing it as just part of my app. So as well as how to just choose a section of the screen as the canvas is it possible to make another activity just like the examples that extends view that I include or can I put everything in MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can create a fragment, or as many as you want, and them place the fragment(s) wherever you want in the activity by using some of the available layouts.

For example, you can use a relative layout. You can add a frame layout to the relative layout and align it in the activity where you want, set its size, and then add the fragment to it. You can check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) link to learn about fragments and their usage if you don't know them.